# Accessing state in redux store from App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In my `ReactNative` app, I'm using `Redux` for state management and I declare the `Provider` in my `App.js` -- see below. Notice that I changed my `App.js` from a function component to a class component.

My question is how do I access data in my `Redux` store in my `App.js`? When I try the following code, I get an error that reads:

> Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"

Here's the `App.js` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { store } from '../store';

// Components
import ComponentA from '../ComponentA';
import ComponentB from '../ComponentB';

class App extends Component {

   render() {
      return(
        <Provider store={store}>
           {
              this.props.isAuthenticated ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
           }
        </Provider>
      );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        isAuthenticated: state.app.isAuthenticated
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Is this an anti-pattern? It does feel like it. Is it better to handle my `isAuthenticated` check in the next component that I embed within the `App.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not recommended to write a provider inside the other data access component and its a bad practise to write a code in that way.

please define an authentication component and render it inside that app component.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the state by calling the getState method from the store:

```
 store.getState();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { rootReducer } from '../store';

// Components
import ComponentA from '../ComponentA';
import ComponentB from '../ComponentB';

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

class App extends Component {

   render() {
      return(
        <Provider store={store}>
           {
              this.props.isAuthenticated ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />
           }
        </Provider>
      );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        isAuthenticated: state.app.isAuthenticatenter code hereed
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```